# Why doesn't get_context_data() get called when overriding dispatch() in Django?

Tags: django

I overrided dispatch() to return a 200 OK for my PayPal IPN, but get_context_data() never gets called. Any idea why?

```
class IPN(TemplateView):
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
            logger.debug("dispatching now")
            return HttpResponse('<h1>Page was found</h1>')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #verify ipn and create user account
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The original `dispatch` decides which HTTP method that the view implements should be called - such as the method `get`..

in most `GenericView`s the `get` method (as an example) calls `get_context_data`..

if you've overridden the dispatch to not call the proper HTTP method then it won't get called.

== edit ==

now that you have posted your code we can see that you didn't call the `get` method or any other HTTP method that the view implements. You just returned a response, and so you never called the  `get_context_data`

Answer (score 2):

You can call

```
super(IPN, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

in your `dispatch` if you want some code to be run in `dispatch`. If it's not the case, you should override `get` method in your view and `get_context_data` will be called automatically.

Answer (score 1):

As you've been told before, neither `dispatch` not `get_context_data` are the right methods to be overriding here. `dispatch` is really only to determine whether to call `get` or `post`: you should override either or both of those. And `get_context_data` is for providing context data for rendering a template: if you're not rendering a template, you shouldn't be overriding that method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have a clear Idea how django CBVs work (e.g TemplateView), don't worry its a little complicated if you have just started with them.

**Read this article** : http://www.gregaker.net/2012/apr/19/how-do-django-class-based-views-work/

It goes pretty deep till the `dispatch()` method and **describes how everything is interconnected** in a TemplateView.

Please take out 10 mins and read, it will really help and you will understand by yourself, what you are missing in you code. :)

Comment: Above link in the answer you've provided is 404 now. Please update link or add some insights manually. And without the working link, this answer is no more useful.